# How to list the source and target branches of all merges in a git repo?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I'm trying to do an analysis of our git repository.  I want to compare merges into our development branch with our release cycle.  To see, for instance, if people are waiting until the end of the cycle to merge changes down.

To do this I want to get a list of all merges into the 'development' branch, the name of the branch being merged down (this lets me know if it was a feature or a defect being merged), the date time, author, and the number of files changed.

I started by pulling a list of SHAs for all commits with:

`git log --pretty=format:%H`

And then cycling through those one by one to see if they're a merge using:

`git show --summary --format="%P" $SHA`

(Commits with > 1 parent are merges).   However, I can't figure out how to narrow it down to *only* merges into development and I can't figure out how to identify the name of the branch being merged down.

I considered parsing the summary:

`git show -s --format="%s" $SHA`

And looking for a pattern like:

> Merge branch '' into 'development'

But in some cases, it looks like the summary was overwritten.  For example, I found a merge (greater than 1 parent commit) that had this as the summary:

> yay unit tests

I've explored parsing the git log graph and reflog but couldn't make any progress.

Is it possible to determine the source and target branch name of a git merge?

Comment: Branches in git is ephemeral, they leave no permanent trace after being deleted. Well, other than the commits that was done on the branch assuming those were merged into branches that still exist. Nothing in a commit records which branch it was committed on. Sure, you can introduce specific ways to format your commit messages to record this information but git does not in any way care about this. If you want to extract this kind of information later you're on your own. Think of a git branch as a post-it note that just marks where a branch is currently at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merges are just commits with >1 parent. There is no preserved data that indicates the branch names on either side of the merge, since branches are just pointers to a particular commit anyway. If the branch names are not preserved in the commit message, that information is likely lost (but see comments below about the reflog).

For example, if you have a graph like this (arrows point from child to parent):

```
                /- D <-\
A <-- B <-- C <-+      +- F
                \- E <-/
```

And you have two branches, master pointing at F and feature-x pointing at E, you can surmise that D was committed against master and E was committed against feature-x.

But this may not be the case -- maybe D was committed on some other branch that master was later fast-forwarded through.

Once feature-x is merged into master (fast-forward to F) then there is really not much information remaining to tell you that E was committed against feature-x.  Commits D and E don't particularly relate to any branch at this point.

I'm only talking about information that gets synchronized on push/fetch, however.  You bring up an interesting point with the reflog.  You might be able to reconstruct this information by examining the reflog of every branch, and using each reflog entry to associate the particular commit with that branch, so in theory it *is* actually possible to reconstruct this information -- or at least *your* repository's particular view of it.  Another clone might contain reflog data that conflicts with the higher-level view you are trying to achieve here.  (A fresh clone will have no useful data to reconstruct this history.)

You will probably have to write your own script to do this analysis: for each branch, for each reflog entry, associate the reflog entry's commit with the branch.  Now look at the parents of each merge, and if there is an association to each parent or some ancestor of the parent, that *might* be the branch that was merged.

Comment: I see.  Forgetting the branch names is it possible to filter out commits that were merges into a particular branch?  Say only merges into my development branch?

Comment: @ChrisSeltzer That's not directly possible for the same reason -- but see my edit regarding the reflog.